# How to make this table in Latex using just tabular?

Tags: tables

I would like to make this table with tabular. But I couldn't figure it out. [image]

Comment: You need `\multicolumn` and `\cline` commands

Comment: Is it hard? do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There are many questions about this on TeX.SE and this is clearly a duplicate question (but I am too lazy to search ;-)

Comment: You'll need to load `multirow`. It's not really hard.

Comment: I have seen that people use these packages. The problem is the unique row on top of the table. I don't know how to generate that one.

Comment: Are all four columns supposed to have equal widths? If so, what's the target *overall* width supposed to be?

Comment: your request is "o-it-for-me" .... what you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the one you are looking for?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=.45in,right=.45in,top=.6in,bottom=.6in,headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Minimization with respect to}\\ \hline
 \multirow{ 2}{*}{Model}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Fields}\\ \cline{2-4}
 &$u$&$n$&$\bar{n}$\\ \hline
  Local &  & & \\ \hline
  Non Local &  & & \\ \hline
  Micro &  & & \\ \hline

\end{tabular}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

with equal width in last three columns

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=.45in,right=.45in,top=.6in,bottom=.6in,headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|}
    \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Minimization with respect to}\\ \hline
 \multirow{ 2}{*}{Model}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Fields}\\ \cline{2-4}
 &$u$&$n$&$\bar{n}$\\ \hline
  Local &  & & \\ \hline
  Non Local &  & & \\ \hline
  Micro &  & & \\ \hline

\end{tabular}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that is really nice. But how to make the width of the fields equal.

Comment: use array package to accomplish  `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}`@M.Rock

Comment: after all, this table is not possible to write only with `tabular` ...

Comment: why `m{...}`? `p{...}` should be sufficient (and you not need to use `array`. and instead `\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Fields}` is correct `\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Fields}`

Comment: +1 for your service " I-will-do-instead-of you" :)